# I need a regexp_like to validate only letters D or T, numbers and Pipe

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, oracle11g

I would like to use Oracle's regexp_like to only allow the following:

- Letters D or T
- Any number including decimal and negative
- special character Pipe  |

Really appreciate your input :)

**Following are valid lines**

```
D|1005433608369|202311220039403004157|2023112200394030041570002|0|-53|4157|20231122|30|394|820|2|0|0|0|0
D|1006233842021|202311220039403004160|2023112200394030041600001|1|0|4160|20231122|30|394|868|1|46002136|98|35|0
D|1006233842021|202311220039403004160|2023112200394030041600002|0|-63|4160|20231122|30|394|820|2|0|0|0|0
D|1004420222359|202311220039403004161|2023112200394030041610001|1|0|4161|20231122|30|394|868|1|45941436|108|54|0
D|1004420222359|202311220039403004161|2023112200394030041610002|0|-54|4161|20231122|30|394|820|2|0|0|0|0
D|1005557156227|202311220039403004187|2023112200394030041870001|1|0|4187|20231122|30|394|868|1|46189226|98|2
```

**Following is an invalid line**

```
T|2401|20231124|202311240240138702117|1015453705|5|193|00 A+%?Pu?Z?3<???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your actual sample data which implies that `D` or `T` would only appear at the very beginning of the line, followed by pipe separated numbers, the following query should work:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '^[DT](\|-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+$')
```

If `D` or `T` could really appear anywhere in the pipe separated string, then we would have to do more work:

```
^(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[DT])(\|(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\|[DT]))*$
```

Oracle query:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '^(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[DT])(\|(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[DT]))*$');
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the line
- `(`

  - `-?` optional leading negative sign
  - `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` an integer or decimal
  - `|` OR
  - `[DT]` the letters `D` or `T`
- `)`
- `(`

  - `\|` pipe separator
  - `(`

    - `-?` optional leading negative sign
    - `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` an integer or decimal
    - `\|` OR
    - `[DT]` the letters `D` or `T`
  - `)`
- `)*` pipe then number/letter expression zero or more following times
- `$` end of the line

Comment: It works great
Enjoy your coffe :)    Gracias

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for your test cases:

```
^[DT](\|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+$
```

In the query:

```sql
select col
from my_table
where REGEXP_LIKE(col, '^[DT](\|-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+$')
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kYf-itCl).

Answer (score 0):

Not that regular expression can't do that, but - it is kind of *complicated*. So, what about another approach, which might perform better on large data sets? `translate` function.

Sample data; `ID = 7` is invalid and should be returned by the query.

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2  (-- valid
  3  select 1, 'D|1005433608369|202311220039403004157|2023112200394030041570002|0|-53|4157|20231122|30|394|820|2|0|0|0|0' from dual union all
  4  select 2, 'D|1006233842021|202311220039403004160|2023112200394030041600001|1|0|4160|20231122|30|394|868|1|46002136|98|35|0' from dual union all
  5  select 3, 'D|1006233842021|202311220039403004160|2023112200394030041600002|0|-63|4160|20231122|30|394|820|2|0|0|0|0' from dual union all
  6  select 4, 'D|1004420222359|202311220039403004161|2023112200394030041610001|1|0|4161|20231122|30|394|868|1|45941436|108|54|0' from dual union all
  7  select 5, 'D|1004420222359|202311220039403004161|2023112200394030041610002|0|-54|4161|20231122|30|394|820|2|0|0|0|0' from dual union all
  8  select 6, 'D|1005557156227|202311220039403004187|2023112200394030041870001|1|0|4187|20231122|30|394|868|1|46189226|98|2' from dual union all
  9  -- invalid
 10  select 7, 'T|2401|20231124|202311240240138702117|1015453705|5|193|00 A+%?Pu?Z?3<???' from dual
 11  )
```

Query:

```
 12  select ID
 13  from test
 14  where translate(col, 'xDT-0123456789.|', 'x') is not null;

        ID
----------
         7

SQL>
```